# Do we need a micro-gravity tag separate from Zero-G?

Tags: discussion, tags

In a recent question (Fire in Zero-G) it was accurately pointed out that micro-G and zero-G are not the same thing (and rightly so).  Is it worth having these tags separately?, or can they be synonyms?  I find zero-g is most often used incorrectly to represent Mirco-gravity anyway, maybe this is best as a synonym?

(I do realize there is a thread saying not to ask about tag creation, this is one of those border line tag-differentiation / tag- synonym / tag - creation questions that I thought was worth defining)

Comment: They could be regrouped into [tag:gravity] to make things simpler. It's pretty much the same topic for me.

Comment: According to [NASA](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/glenn/shuttlestation/station/microgex.html#.VG-aUPkq93Y), with some liberal paraphrasing, it's all relative. I agree with Vincent. (See paragraph 4)

Comment: I'd agree with @Vincent as well, gravity is gravity, the strength of said gravity shouldn't be included in the tag.  if zero-G and micro-G are distinct, wouldn't earth-like-gravity and high-gravity make sense as tags as well?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think there are going to be enough questions to warrant tags for specific types of gravity.

Answer (score 4):

The [zero-g](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-g) tag already has a description **"For questions about zero or low gravity environments".** Since zero g is nearly always short hand for some degree of low gravity, there is no need for a separate tag.

In time [zero-g](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-g) may be absorbed into [gravity](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravity), but there is no need for action at this point. There is nothing to be gained by adding a new tag for micro gravity, since the zero g tag works perfectly well. The distinction is not important since true zero g is unattainable in any practical setting.

Comment: As a separate issue, I think that zero-g should be renamed to zero-gravity to [aid the tag auto suggest](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/540/should-zero-g-be-renamed-zero-gravity-to-aid-the-auto-suggest/541#541).

Answer (score -1):

As per vincent's comment, I believe using the less specific term 'Gravity' is preferential over breaking out specific gravity types such as Zero-Gravity, Micro-Gravity, High-Gravity, Earth-like-gravity and all the other possibilities that ultimately refer to specific strengths of Gravity.

Comment: Tagging is an emergent folksonomy and we shouldn't aggressively re-name tags and impose structure until there's a *problem* with the way it's emerging which needs structure to fix. At that time, this will probably be the right move. Until then, we should just watch and learn.