# Should zero-g be renamed zero-gravity to aid the auto suggest?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

If I tag something [gravity](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravity) then while typing it [zero-g](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-g) will not be suggested. However, if we instead had a [zero-gravity](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-gravity) tag then while typing the word "gravity", both tags would be suggested.

Since this would only involve adding a few letters to the tag (for which there are only 4 questions to consider), is there any reason not to do this?

Answer (score 13):

### We should *always* avoid abbreviations of important words in tags.

You've just run into one major reason why: it makes it harder to find the tag.

So yes, we really should change this tag to spell out "gravity."

Comment: +1 for idea of no abbreviations of important words in tags, -1 for changing the tag instead of just renaming it to gravity, +1 for reasoning behind why no abbreviations from tags.  My upand down votes tend to cancel each other out.

Comment: @Twelfth We aren't talking about replacing the tag here. That's what [this page](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/538/65) is for.

Comment: (yep, this is why it adds up to a +1 and me agreeing with you)

Comment: Yes, abbreviations should be avoided. In this case, "zero G" is a fairly well known term to folks *in the know*, but we cater to a wider audience. Tag names can be [up to 24 characters long](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (actually, that page states "shorter than 25 characters") and we should use that length to try to find tag names that are **descriptive** and **easy to find**.

Comment: Ideally, we want newcomers to the site to stumble across the correct tag(s) for a question *by accident* rather than having to search for them in any way. A newcomer's question might still require retagging (in part because some appropriate tags may be non-obvious to someone not knowledgable about the subject, which is likely why they would be asking here in the first place), but the easier we make it on them to find the (or at least *some*) correct tags, the better.

Comment: While I'm not against this renaming, I anyway want to tell you that "zero-g" is *not* the abbreviation of "zero-gravity", but g is an unit of gravitational acceleration (on earth's surface we have 1g, by definition). In weightlessness, the gravitational acceleration is, of course, 0g.

Answer (score 3):

I have renamed the [zero-g](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-g) tag to [zero-gravity](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-gravity).

Note that this change *may* take some time to fully propagate throughout the site. It however looks to me like the process is complete.

Answer (score -3):

In conjunction with the other thread on the topic here [Do we need a micro-gravity tag separate from Zero-G?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/538/do-we-need-a-micro-gravity-tag-separate-from-zero-g)

...I think Zero-G should either be a synonym of Gravity or completely removed in favor of just using the gravity tag as it's covered by the more generic gravity tag.  Makes this a bit moot.

Comment: I don't think it's obvious that zero-g should be absorbed into gravity. I'd recommend you add an answer to the question you linked to, so we can see if the community agrees.

Comment: Right, forgot the meta vote use for these purposes.  Answer is in

Comment: My downvote is not a comment on merging into [tag:gravity] (I think that will be the correct thing to do, but I don't know if we should do it now), but rather because this answer conflates that issue with the naming one.  Whether it's a tag or a synonym, the zero-something thing needs a name, which is what this question is about.