# Please merge and perhaps synonymize [microgravity] and [zero-gravity] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

We currently have [zero-gravity](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-gravity) and [microgravity](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microgravity).

As discussed in [Do we need a micro-gravity tag separate from Zero-G?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/538/29), in many situations these two are effectively the same thing. The tag wiki excerpt for the microgravity tag even reads (boldface added):

> For questions about environments with extremely low perceived gravity (**colloquially referred to as "zero gravity",** usually referring to a free-fall environment in space) and the impact of such environments on creatures and technology.

The tag wiki excerpt for the zero-gravity tag reads:

> For questions about zero or low gravity environments

I feel that the two tags should be merged.

For discoverability, it might be beneficial to have a "zero gravity" tag *synonym*. However, since (absent the term *free fall environment*) the technically more correct term in almost all cases is microgravity, I suggest that microgravity should be the main tag.

Note that microgravity can apply to Earthbound situations as well; for example, it could be applicable on a question about unrestrained falling elevators.

Comment: Specifically, please emphasize that [tag:zero-gravity] should be synonym for [tag:microgravity], because the latter is more technically valid term. Just burninating one of them would not be a good move.

Comment: @Mołot I edited the second-to-last paragraph ("For discoverability, ...") slightly to emphasize that, which was indeed already my intent.

Comment: Can't we just use gravity?

Comment: @Vincent Only if you're willing to extend the usage of that tag considerably. Note the current tag wiki excerpt there: *For questions about the universal accelerative force between all objects.* https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravity

Comment: I don't see a problem in doing that.

Comment: I'd argue strongly against merging with gravity. 'Gravity' relates to kinetic physics: falling under gravity, potential energy, acceleration, orbital physics, equation of gravitation, etc; and architectural and biological support structures. 'microgravity' relates to things like biology, liquids (surface tension, bubbles, buoyancy), friction, preservation of momentum. Different classes of question, appealing to different people and interests.

Comment: @Michael Korning: But it's not an answer. I was responding to Vincent's idea of merging with Gravity, not to the idea of merging "zero gravity" and "microgravity" (which I support, since the technical difference is so insignificant and nuanced that you couldn't expect anyone to respect or be aware of it)

Comment: I could be for merging the tags, but I'd want to be careful to recognize that we're merging them because, as world builders, the difference between them is small enough to ignore, as opposed to arguing they are identical.

Comment: @CortAmmon That's why I wouldn't be making a similar argument on [space.se] or [physics.se]. Of course, on those, I would instead propose that the tag wiki is changed to make the distinction far more clear.